# Zero padding (Tail Bits) in convolutional encoder. VHDL

Tags: vhdl, fpga

Here is the entity of top-level module of the convolutional encoder. I wants to do zero padding to input_tdata when input_tlast = '1'. The problem is input_tlast is high for just 1 clock cycle, but I want to add (k-1) zeros in as many clock cycles, where k=7. any help?

```
entity conv_encoder is

    Port (

           clk         : in STD_LOGIC;
           rst         : in STD_LOGIC;

           input_tvalid : in STD_LOGIC; 
           input_tdata  : in STD_LOGIC; -- Input data to be encoded
           input_tlast  : in STD_LOGIC; --Indicates End of Packet

           output_tvalid   : out STD_LOGIC;

           y_out_1         : out STD_LOGIC;
           y_out_2         : out STD_LOGIC;        
           output_tdata    : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (1 downto 0)
           );
end conv_encoder;
```

Comment: Please remove the CSS tag and improve your code layout.

Answer (score 0):

In general case you will have to build a FIFO with a sufficient depth. The write side will be connected to the input, the read side will be connected to the output. When input_tlast is asserted, you pause reading from the FIFO and insert zeroes into the output using a count-down.

It depends on the details of the requirements whether you can simplify this. For example, if after "End of Packet" the input data can be discarded, then you don't really need a FIFO.